# Error No file found while converting file present in s3 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

- I have a csv files present in s3
- I am able to print bucket name, key and file content
- But while converting to json I am getting Error no file found
- There is only one csv file which is of 1 KB

code is below

```
import boto3
import csv
import json

# set up S3 connection
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

my_bucket = s3.Bucket('csvfolder3')
# bucket_name = 'csvfolder3'

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(file.key)
        body = file.get()['Body'].read()
        print(body)
        with open(file.key, 'r') as csvfile: #####[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'

            data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile)]
            json_data = json.dumps(data)
        s3.Object(my_bucket, 'file.json').put(Body=json_data)
```

Comment: `open()` looks for a file on your local hard drive.  Presumably you meant to open a file in the s3 bucket instead?

Comment: how do you expect this to work? you are looping over `my_bucket.objects.all()` - all the objects in an **S3** bucket. You are running in an **AWS Lambda** function. Note, that your Lambda function does not *magically* have all (or any) of your S3 objects already downloaded and available for use in a local directory, or /tmp folder in this case.

Comment: @rv.kvetch There is only one csv file which is of 1 KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have:

```py
body = file.get()['Body'].read()
```

This is already downloading the file (or object) *contents* in memory, within the AWS Lambda function.

> ***N.B***: keep an eye on the memory (MB) consumed. Increase memory size for the Lambda function as needed.

Further, I am assuming - based on the docs - that `['Body'].read()` returns a `bytes` object.

So if you have `bytes`, you can then turn it into a string with:

```py
bytes_data.decode()
```

Then create a *file-like object* as `csv.DictReader` expects, by wrapping the above with:

```py
StringIO(...)
```

Full example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import csv
import json
from io import StringIO

byte_content = b"""
id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
""".strip()

# set encoding if known
encoding = 'utf-8'

# decode bytes -> str
content = byte_content.decode(encoding)

# create file-like object
file = StringIO(content)

data: list[dict] = [row for row in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=",")]

json_data: str = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(json_data)
```

Result:

```py
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20",
    "height": "62",
    "weight": "120.6"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Freddie",
    "age": "21",
    "height": "74",
    "weight": "190.6"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": "17",
    "height": "68",
    "weight": "120.0"
  }
]
```

Comment: if i want to convert directly without  `body = file.get()['Body'].read()`, what should I do? Also I am getting error  #####[ERROR] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'

Comment: My understanding, is its not possible to convert csv directly to json. the reason is that your data is in CSV format, and you want to have it as JSON. There are two approaches: 1) read file from S3 as bytes, and wrap it into a file-like object or (2) read file from S3 as bytes, and save to a local `/tmp` folder, and pass in an actual file object with `open`. Of those two approaches, I would argue that the first is the most straightforward one. In either case, you will need to leverage `csv.DictReader` or similar to convert from CSV > `dict` > JSON.

Answer (score 1):

like @rv.kvetch mentioned there are two way to convert file,

first method is already done by him

adding the second method

```
import boto3
import csv
import json
import os

# set up S3 connection
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get bucket name and file name from event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    # download CSV file from S3
    csv_file_path = f'/tmp/{file_name}'
    s3.download_file(bucket_name, file_name, csv_file_path)
    
    # convert CSV data to JSON format
    with open(csv_file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
        data = [row for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile)]
        json_data = json.dumps(data)

    # upload JSON data to S3
    json_file_path = f'{os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]}.json'
    s3.put_object(Body=json_data, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=json_file_path)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('CSV to JSON conversion successful!')
    }
```